# ESRI ArcGIS Online/Portal time stop the time conversion from UTC to local

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, arcgis-portal

I have a FME script in which in which I am reading data from one source containing two datetime columns. These datetime columns are in UTC and I am converting them to my local time and then writing the final output in an enterprise geodatabase feature class.

I published this feature class to my Portal and the issue is that my end users, who are from different countries are getting datetime columns converted again to their respective local time which is giving them wrong time.

For resolving this, I created one text column and placed datetime in my local time and then from ArcGIS Online I created a new column using Arcade expression. This Arcade expression is parsing the datetime in text column and creating a datetime object, which works fine as long as it is done using old map viewer. For new map viewer it only appears in Popup and not the attribute table.

Is there a way to stop this auto adjustment of datetime from UTC to local?

Comment: Best practice is to always write datetime data to the database in UTC. It's probably JavaScript which is converting the time, so this is a "feature" of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

From Esri: https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/work-with-date-fields.htm

> **How dates are displayed**
>
> The client you use to view the data determines how date and time
> values are displayed. When a date field is displayed in the portal,
> the date is converted from UTC to your local time. This is done by
> querying your computer and asking it for its time zone setting. For
> example, suppose your computer is set to Pacific standard time (PST).
> PST is eight hours behind UTC—when UTC is 9:00 a.m, it is 1:00 a.m.
> PST (or 2:00 a.m. if daylight saving time is in effect).
>
> **Change the display format of a date field**
>
> You can change how dates are displayed in the table in your portal.
> Tables display with the same formatting configured in pop-ups. You can
> change the display format of a date field by selecting the field alias
> in the Configure Attributes window of Pop-up Properties.